# Node references - show view link, rather than create link, if already exists

Tags: nodes

I've searched all over to try and find a solution for this - hoping I've just been searching for the wrong stuff :)

Sounds easy, and I know it has to be, just have to find a way to do it within D7.

So, building a little calendar event manager. I have a custom content type for calendar events. Using Node References to tie an 'event application' (also a content type) to those events.  So users can come and sign up for an event.  We have an application approval process, which complicates this whole matter.

Nevertheless, it works great right now.  They view the calendar event node, and they can click on a signup link (put there by Node References).  But if they've already signed up, I'd like to just show them a link to view their current application, or maybe even a link to edit it and resubmit.  Something like that.   People are signing up for an event multiple times because they keep seeing the sign up link lol.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could create a views template for that field of your row, and in there put whatever logic you need to display either the signup or view link.  clicking on theme information in the views UI will bring up the names of the templates, and the original code in them, that you would need to modify and then save into your theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using Views for this (at least not at the moment).  The calendar events show up on the home page, and the signup link shows when they view that node (and in the teaser).  That link is put there by the Node Reference module. :(

Comment: Ah, well, you could use the preprocess_node() hook and in there use whatever logic you need to figure out what link you want to show, and then either change up your $node then and there, or, set a variable and then in a custom node.tpl.php for that nodetype, render the field appropriately in there based upon that variable.